# Помогите с условием из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, условия

Здравствуйте. Имеется такая задача:
1) Проверить есть ли доступ к устройству. Если устройство доступно, записать "0" ежели нет, записать "1" (Выполнено).

```
$execute = curl_init('http://example.com');
    curl_exec($execute);

    $alive = '0';
    $dead = '1';

    if (!curl_errno($execute)) {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `arduino` SET `status` = '" . $alive . "', `insertion_time` = '" . time() . "'");
    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `arduino` SET `status` = '" . $dead . "', `insertion_time` = '" . time() . "'");
        mysql_close();
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($execute);
```

2) Если устройство доступно и последним значением в таблице установлено "1", отправить запрос на выполнение. (Выполнено).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `status` FROM `arduino` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['status'] == 1) {
        $execute = curl_init('http://example.com/?execute');
        curl_exec($execute);
        curl_close($execute);
    } else {
        echo 'Выполнение запущено!';
    }
}
```

**Теперь собственно вопрос:**
Каким образом, мне создать условие, если допустим значение "0" было установлено в 12:00, тогда запрос на выполнение отправлять через 10 минут?
Надеюсь всё доступно обьяснил.

Comment: а каким образом вы узнаете, когда было установлено значение 0 ? у вас в БД явно не хватает колонки с датой события. вот если бы она была, то вы бы просто в select посмотрели сколько времени прошло с последнего 0 события и если больше 10 минут то выполнили бы

Comment: в БД имеется колонка с датой, в запросе видно же.

Comment: @Mike `insertion_time` не?

Comment: Да, все верно..

Comment: Я на select смотрел, а он вообще из другой таблицы оказывается и не понятно какое отношение имеет производимый insert, к тому select что во второй части. Так если время есть то вопрос то в чем, получаете последнюю запись из БД, убеждаетесь что у нее статус 0 и время вставки меньше текущего на 10 минут и запускаете то что требуется

Comment: В том то и дело, я не знаю как это реализовать. Я только недавно начал вникать в PHP и работу с БД MySQL.Мне хотелось бы увидеть наглядный пример.

Comment: непонятна Ваша фраза "тогда запрос на выполнение отправлять через 10 минут" - какой запрос? еще какой-то третий?

Comment: Да, будет еще запрос, но это не важно. Мне нужно само условие. Дальше я сам:)